# VBA - Application Defined or Object Defined Error?

Tags: excel, vba

I have been working on this most the day and can't seem to figure it out. Here is what I am trying to do (should be pretty simple):

Two Workbooks: one opened already (ThisWorkbook) and one opened through Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen) (we will call this Workbook 2)

1. If Column K is blank in ThisWorkbook."Sheet1" then search for values in Column M and Column P in Workbook 2."503 Sundry", Column B and G respectively.
2. If values match in Workbook2."503 Sundry" then copy values from Column H and Column I and paste into ThisWorkbook."Sheet1", Columns I and K respectively.

This is what I have so far, but I keep getting an error message "Application defined or object defined error" on the bolded line of code below.

```
  Sub JPlan()

  Dim wb1 As Workbook
  Dim wb2 As Workbook
  Dim cell1 As Range, rng1 As Range, cell2 As Range, rng2 As Range
  Dim Cel As Range
  Dim Sht1 As Worksheet
  Dim SundrySht As Worksheet

  Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook

  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
      If .Show Then
          Filename = .SelectedItems(1)
          Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename)
      Else
          Exit Sub
      End If
  End With

  Set Sht1 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")
  Set SundrySht = wb2.Sheets("503 Sundry")

  Set Cel = Sht1.Range("P2")
  Set rng1 = Range(Cel, Cel.Offset(Sht1.Cells.Rows.Count - Cel.Row, 0).End(xlUp))
  Set Cel = SundrySht.Range("G2")
  Set rng2 = Range(Cel, Cel.Offset(SundrySht.Cells.Rows.Count - Cel.Row, 0).End(xlUp))

  If Sht1.Cells(i, 11) = "" Then  'if current cell in column 11 is empty then...
    For Each cell2 In rng2        'for each cell in range 2 defined above (column G in "503 Sundry")...
      For Each cell1 In rng1      'for each cell in range 1 defined above (column P in Sheet 1)...
        If cell2.Value = cell1.Value And cell2.Offset(0, -5) = cell1.Offset(0, -3).Value Then   'if the value of cell2 equals the value of cell1 AND the value of cell2 (offset by 5 columns) equals the value of cell1 (offset by 3 columns) then...
          cell1.Offset(0, -7).Value = cell2.Offset(0, 1).Value    'from to Sundry column H to Sheet1 column I
          cell1.Offset(0, -5).Value = cell2.Offset(0, 2).Value    'from to Sundry column I to Sheet1 column K
          Exit For
        End If
      Next
    Next
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: the code view does syntax highlighting, but any bolding you may have applied is lost. Can you find some other way to point to the line that errors?

Comment: There are [938 other existing posts here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvba%5D+application+defined+or+object+defined+error)  that contain that exact error message. How many of them have you read to see if they have an answer to your question before posting yet another one?

Comment: looks like you only set wb2 in one part of the if clause. what happens if you never set it? Most likely a 1004 error lol

Comment: @DougCoats - the other leg of the `If` statement contains `Exit Sub`, so there's no point in setting a local variable in that leg.

Comment: Please include `Option Explicit` as the first line in your code module.  (I assume the line that is generating your error is `If Sht1.Cells(i, 11) = "" Then`, which is crashing out because row 0 is not a valid row number in Excel.)

Answer (score 0):

As there is nothing in your question to indicate which line is generating your 1004 error, I will assume that it is occurring at the line saying `If Sht1.Cells(i, 11) = "" Then`.  This line will fail because you have not declared the variable `i` and, more importantly, you have never assigned a value to it.  It will therefore be assuming that `i` is a `Variant` (nothing particularly bad about that, but making Excel guess as to what variable type to use is not a good habit to get into) with a value of zero.  Excel does not understand the concept of a "row 0", so the 1004 error is thrown.

These sort of issues can be avoided (or, at least, reduced) by including `Option Explicit` as the first line of each of your code modules.  This tells the compiler to throw an error highlighting any variables which you have not explicitly declared in your code.  (It would also highlight the fact that you have not declared the variable `Filename`.)

The following refactored code avoids the need for either of your two currently undeclared variables:

```
'In order to prevent mistakes due to undefined variables,
'include this as the first line in each code module
Option Explicit

Sub JPlan()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim cell1 As Range, rng1 As Range, cell2 As Range, rng2 As Range

    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show Then
            '"Filename" wasn't declared, so I just merged the two lines
            ' rather than adding a "Dim Filename As String" line
            Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(.SelectedItems(1))
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    With wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set rng1 = .Range(.Cells(2, "P"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp))
    End With
    With wb2.Sheets("503 Sundry")
        Set rng2 = .Range(.Cells(2, "G"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp))
    End With

    'Changing the order of the loops avoids the need for the variable "i"
    For Each cell1 In rng1      'for each cell in range 1 defined above (column P in Sheet 1)...
        If cell1.Offset(0, -5).Value = "" Then 'if current cell in column 11 is empty then...
            For Each cell2 In rng2        'for each cell in range 2 defined above (column G in "503 Sundry")...
                If cell2.Value = cell1.Value And _
                   cell2.Offset(0, -5).Value = cell1.Offset(0, -3).Value Then   'if the value of cell2 equals the value of cell1 AND the value of cell2 (offset by 5 columns) equals the value of cell1 (offset by 3 columns) then...
                    cell1.Offset(0, -7).Value = cell2.Offset(0, 1).Value    'from to Sundry column H to Sheet1 column I
                    cell1.Offset(0, -5).Value = cell2.Offset(0, 2).Value    'from to Sundry column I to Sheet1 column K
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: So...good news is your code works...but I got some bigger problems and I believe it is formatting. If I copy and paste a random NHA and PN from Workbook2 into Columns M and P and run the code it pulls the data in. However, if I pull the EXACT same NHA and PN from Woorkbook1 and paste it into Columns M and P and run the code it doesn't pull any data in. How does that even make sense? Is the a formatting issue? @YowE3K

Comment: @CC268 I don't know what "NHA" and "PN" are, but your comment about formatting makes me think you may have text in one sheet and numbers in another.  If so, try changing `If cell2.Value = cell1.Value And cell2.Offset(0, -5).Value = cell1.Offset(0, -3).Value Then` to be `If cell2.Text = cell1.Text And cell2.Offset(0, -5).Text = cell1.Offset(0, -3).Text Then`.  That will compare the **displayed** contents of the cells, rather than the **actual** contents of the cells.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @YowE3K. I really appreciate it. I finally got it to work and your code was perfect. Turns out the values in Columns M and P in Workbook 2 were formatted really weird. I had to use the TRIM function because there were all sorts of weird spaces in the cell. That is why it wasn't picking it up when I ran the code. Anyways everything works great now!