# VBA - Two Workbooks: Search for Values in Workbook 2, Copy and Paste in Workbook 1

Tags: excel, vba

Worked on this all day yesterday, but couldn't get it to work. Going to try this again and keep it simple - here is what I want to do:

Two Workbooks: one opened already (ThisWorkbook) and one opened through Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen) (we will call this Workbook 2)

1. If Column K is blank in ThisWorkbook."Sheet1" then search for values in Column M and Column P in Workbook 2."503 Sundry", Column B and G respectively.
2. If values match in Workbook2."503 Sundry" then copy values from Column H and Column I and paste into ThisWorkbook."Sheet1", Columns I and K respectively.

Here is my current code (I am not sure this is a good code to build off - this has been a mess):

```
  Sub JPlan()

  Dim wb1 As Workbook
  Dim wb2 As Workbook
  Dim cell1 As Range, rng1 As Range, cell2 As Range, rng2 As Range
  Dim Cel As Range
  Dim Sht1 As Worksheet
  Dim SundrySht As Worksheet

  Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook

  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
      If .Show Then
          Filename = .SelectedItems(1)
          Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename)
      Else
          Exit Sub
      End If
  End With

  Set Sht1 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")
  Set SundrySht = wb2.Sheets("503 Sundry")

  Set Cel = Sht1.Range("P2")
  Set rng1 = Range(Cel, Cel.Offset(Sht1.Cells.Rows.Count - Cel.Row, 0).End(xlUp))
  Set Cel = SundrySht.Range("G2")
  Set rng2 = Range(Cel, Cel.Offset(SundrySht.Cells.Rows.Count - Cel.Row, 0).End(xlUp))

  If Sht1.Cells(, 11) = "" Then  'if current cell in column 11 is empty then...
    For Each cell2 In rng2        'for each cell in range 2 defined above (column G in "503 Sundry")...
      For Each cell1 In rng1      'for each cell in range 1 defined above (column P in Sheet 1)...
        If cell2.Value = cell1.Value And cell2.Offset(0, -5) = cell1.Offset(0, -3).Value Then   'if the value of cell2 equals the value of cell1 AND the value of cell2 (offset by 5 columns) equals the value of cell1 (offset by 3 columns) then...
          cell1.Offset(0, -7).Value = cell2.Offset(0, 1).Value    'from to Sundry column H to Sheet1 column I
          cell1.Offset(0, -5).Value = cell2.Offset(0, 2).Value    'from to Sundry column I to Sheet1 column K
          Exit For
        End If
      Next
    Next
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You should paste your current code into the question.  That saves us the trouble of having to find [the duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41884492/6535336) so that we can see what is causing your error.

Comment: There you go - @YowE3K

Comment: `Cells(, 11)` works, but won't do what you want.  (It simply defaults the row to 1 - i.e. it's the equivalent of `Cells(1, 11)`.)  See my answer to your earlier question.

Comment: I don't understand...the code doesn't do anything at all..it literally opens up the file in the beginning when I use the Application.FileDialog and that is it. This should be pretty simple, but holy cow I have been struggling with this for two days now.

Comment: If you are using the code above, is cell K1 empty?  If not, the code above will simply open the second workbook, set up `rng1` and `rng2`, look at cell K1 in ThisWorkbook, decide not to do anything within the `If` statement, and end.  See my answer to your earlier question.

Comment: K1 is actually the column heading...but thats why I have the loop...it needs to start by going down column K and only running the rest of the code if the cell in Column K is empty. I just noticed your code on my other thread - I will take a look at it and run it and get back to you!

Comment: "only running the rest of the code if the cell in Column K is empty" - your code above is "only running the rest of the code if cell **K1** is empty"

Comment: So how would I get it to go through the range of K1 to last row in K? I haven't looked at your code yet on my previous thread but I will in the next 30 mins or so

Comment: My answer to your previous question refactored your code so that it would work.  (It actually works using your `rng1` - I assumed that the rows covered by it are the ones you want to process.)

Comment: I commented on my other post regarding your code